# Topic publishing rate slows down after message is lost

Tags: ros, rate, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that receives an `image` topic, then it process the image and publishes a `pose` topic.

From time to time the image is not processed correctly and the `pose` topic is not published.

When the algorithm finds the pose again, it starts publishing again, but the publishing rate slows down. Or at least that is what `rostopic hz /pose` says.

I checked the code with prints and everything seems to be running at the same speed.

I was wondering if I have to reset something or set a variable to not see this behavior.

```
rostopic hz /pose

subscribed to [/pose]
average rate: 27.734
    min: 0.028s max: 0.103s std dev: 0.00686s window: 238
average rate: 27.239
    min: 0.028s max: 0.103s std dev: 0.00693s window: 261
average rate: 26.142
    min: 0.028s max: 0.123s std dev: 0.00884s window: 303
average rate: 26.106
    min: 0.028s max: 0.123s std dev: 0.00878s window: 308
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 14.935
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.66048s window: 562
average rate: 15.190
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.64626s window: 587
average rate: 15.403
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.63343s window: 611
average rate: 15.601
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.62183s window: 634
average rate: 15.634
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.61988s window: 638
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 13.446
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.70729s window: 829
average rate: 13.625
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.69688s window: 854
average rate: 13.786
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.68729s window: 878
average rate: 13.935
    min: 0.028s max: 15.696s std dev: 0.67885s window: 900
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 10.006
    min: 0.028s max: 25.862s std dev: 1.09056s window: 908
average rate: 10.182
    min: 0.028s max: 25.862s std dev: 1.07530s window: 934
average rate: 10.340
    min: 0.028s max: 25.862s std dev: 1.06122s window: 959
average rate: 10.500
    min: 0.028s max: 25.862s std dev: 1.04768s window: 984
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229419/topic-publishing-rate-slows-down-after-message-is-lost/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-18**:
The publishing rate given by `rostopic hz` is an average, you can adjust the size of the window with the `-w`  option, e.g `rostopic hz -w 5 /pose`  to average over 5 messages.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-18**:
@al-dev why don't you post this as an answer?

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-18**:
My bad, I thought the comment could be promoted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The publishing rate given by `rostopic hz` is by default 'the average rate over the entire time rostopic has been running.' : http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_hz
If you want an estimate based on the last N messages(window), you can use the `-w` option, e.g `rostopic hz -w 5 /pose` to average over the last 5 messages.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1